# Problem with custom shader for blending textures in Unity URP project 2021.3.16f

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-development, urp, shader-graph

I have a problem with custom shaders in Unity 2021.3.16f which blends two textures 1 - (1 - target) / blend

[image]

I needed the effect of enhancing one texture on another, but as a result, I got this effect:

[image]

[image]

But the effect in the shader view window looks as it should:

[image]

When I off the global volume, the effect disappears and everything becomes normal. Could it be due to artifacts in the first and last picture ?

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch, but do you perhaps have a light source with an unreasonable brightness in your scene?

Comment: When I off the global volume, the effect disappears and everything becomes normal. Could it be due to artifacts in first and last picture ?

Comment: I don't think that it should, but I'm also unfamiliar with volumetric fog and how it can interact with shaders.

Comment: yea, but it is (